# Have module open popup or isolate module on page after a trigger

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Is there a way to have a SPA module open in a dialog or to isolate it on the page where it is loaded from after a button click? Preferably isolate it on a page, but either option will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the DNN modals for that?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://dnndev.me/testpage">HyperLink1</asp:HyperLink>
```

And then create the popup code url in code behind

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return " + UrlUtils.PopUpUrl(HyperLink1.NavigateUrl, this, PortalSettings, true, false));
```

Comment: it is a html based module, is there a way to add the asp tag to that or does it have to be razor based? Also, it would be preferable to just make the module go full page and hide the other ones if that is possible.